# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm very new to Angular and I'm trying to figure much of this out still.  I'm writing some tests using Angular 1.5.8 which I generated from the Yeoman Generator.

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate $httpBackend results (I'm not sure if that's important or not)...

In my app.js file I have the following code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'breadcrumbService', function ($rootScope, $location, breadcrumbService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
    });

    $rootScope.isEditMode = false;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        // ------------ this next line is failing -----------
        $rootScope.isEditMode = $location.path().toLowerCase().endsWith('/edit') || $location.path().toLowerCase().endsWith('/new');
    });

    $rootScope.parseJson = function (value) {
        return angular.fromJson(value);
    };

    $rootScope.bc = breadcrumbService;

    $rootScope.title = "";
}])
```

The line about halfway down (where I added the comment) is failing.  Specifically, the `endsWith` function is failing (toLower is fine), with this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Service: breadcrumbService should return breadcrumb label in json format FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$location.path().toLowerCase().endsWith('/edit')') in app/scripts/app.js (line 44)
        app/scripts/app.js:44:72
        $broadcast@bower_components/angular/angular.js:18005:33
        bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3353:32
        processQueue@bower_components/angular/angular.js:16383:30
        bower_components/angular/angular.js:16399:39
        $eval@bower_components/angular/angular.js:17682:28
        $digest@bower_components/angular/angular.js:17495:36
        $apply@bower_components/angular/angular.js:17790:31
        done@bower_components/angular/angular.js:11831:53
        handleResponse@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1368:17
        flush@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1808:26
        test/spec/services/breadcrumbservice.js:33:27
        invoke@bower_components/angular/angular.js:4718:24
        workFn@bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3085:26
```

Here is my test code (some junk modified from different examples - just trying to get it to work):

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: breadcrumbService', function () {

    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler;
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        console.log('Is null? '+ ($httpBackend == null));
        $httpBackend.whenGET(/views\/.*/).respond(200, [{}, {}, {}]);

        authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/v1/SiteStagings')
            .respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

        // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    // instantiate service
    var breadcrumbService;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_breadcrumbService_) {
        breadcrumbService = _breadcrumbService_;
    }));

    it('svc should exist', function () {
        expect(!!breadcrumbService).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should return breadcrumb label in json format', function () {
        var result = breadcrumbService.getFromCache('site', 'SiteGroupStagings', 46, 'SiteGroupDesc');
        console.log(result);
        expect(!!result).toBe(true);

    });
});
```

I don't doubt that I'm doing something wrong here, I just can't quite understand what it is.  What does this error really mean and why does it not like my call to `endsWith`?

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> undefined is not a constructor

is an error message PhantomJS displays when you tried to call a function that is not defined. It depends on the version of ECMAScript which your PhantomJS supports. So as you said it works fine in Chrome, because this browser supports the function you are using in test.
In order to fix your problem and still be able to use PhantomJS you can replace the "unknown to PhantomJS" function with some alternative function.

Comment: sure would be cooler if it said "you tried to call a function that is not defined"

Comment: Enabling some polyfills also does the trick with PhantomJS, you don't have to manually replace the missing function.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor` error using the `includes()` method. The `includes()` and `endsWith()` methods are new in ECMAScript 2015, and are not supported in Internet Explorer, and evidently not by PhantomJS.

There is a chance your end user may be using Internet Explorer. In which case, you may want to use the fully supported `indexOf()` method instead of `includes()` or `endsWith()`

For example, in my case, everything worked great in chrome, but my tests were failing on the line:

```
if (item.name.includes('contents'))
```

I changed to using the indexOf() method instead:

```
if (item.name.indexOf('contents') !== -1)
```

And then I was no longer getting the error

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor

Comment: This is definitely the issue. I don't need to support IE, so I left my code as is and added a mock service instead of the actual service which had the method using `include` syntax.

Answer (score 10):

I debated whether or not to post this as an answer or just an edit to my question, but I guess it's my answer (for now):

It seems the problem is related to PhantomJS.  As soon as I changed the engine to Chrome in the karma.conf.js file, those tests passed.

I still don't know what that error message is supposed to mean and why it wasn't working with PhantomJS, but at least I'm now able to continue.

Here are the modifications to my karma.conf.js (in case anyone is curious):

```
browsers: [
 //'PhantomJS',
 'Chrome'
],

// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
 'karma-chrome-launcher',
 //'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
 'karma-jasmine'
],
```

Btw - I did notice that `endsWith` is new to ECMAScript6 (I was thinking it was older), but WebStorm shows that it's referencing a helper function in angular-ui-grid.  I spent quite a while messing with the `files` array in the karma.conf.js file in an attempt to see if the ui-grid dependency was loading too late or something.  In every test, it worked fine in Chrome but not PhantomJS.  I still have no idea why.

Comment: I am having similar issues with PhantomJS. Most of the time all tests pass, but other times they all fail with the same error "TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating  ...". Only happens with PhantomJS on Windows. Using Chrome the errors never occur.

Answer (score 6):

**In My Case: Cyclic Dependencies Causing:**

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '(0, _actions.prefix)('SET_USER_INPUT_PHONE_NUMBER')')   at undefined:12

I got the same error after I added imports in my javascript production code (ES6 syntax compiled with babel/webpack).
The changes were fine when a production build of the application was loaded in chrome but running the tests with phantomJS produced the error.
In my case the added imports created cyclic dependencies.

I'm dropping this here for future reference (I stumbled upon the same problem a few weeks ago and don't want to scratch my head again in another couple of weeks) and for others that google the same error.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well when running unit test and suspect that it's circular module dependency at work as well. Thanks for the post.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it is of help to others too, and not only to me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error with PhantomJS:

For me the error was the way in which I was creating a spy object for my service.

Error on line in code file `new Service.getData(param1, param2)`

Fix in test file: `jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',['getData'])`

What is was missing was adding `['getData]` while creating spyObj