# Event Emitter Javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Hi i am a newbie in javascript. I am implementing emitter on function in javascript and i have trouble in testing it using jasmine framework. Below is the function emitter on and code to test the function.

//main.js

```
Emitter.prototype.on = function (event, listener) 
{
    if (typeof this.events[event] !== 'object') 
    {
        this.events[event] = [];
     }

     this.events[event].push(listener);
 };
```

//test.js

```
describe('#on', () => 
{
    it('should subscribe to an event name and be called when 
    triggered', () => 
{

    Emitter.on(EVENT_NAME_ONE, spyFunction);
    //Emitter.trigger(EVENT_NAME_ONE);

    expect(spyFunction.calls.count()).toBe(1);
 });
```

The above mentioned test fails. I am not sure why. Can someone please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details. what the test failure prints? where did spyFunction came from?

Comment: beforeEach(() => {spyFunction = jasmine.createSpy('EMPTY_FUNCTION_ONE');});  spy function is created as shown in above statement.  Below is the error:  FAILED TESTS:
  emitter
    #on
      ✖ should subscribe to an event name and be called when triggered
        PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)
      TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Emitter.on(EVENT_NAME_ONE, spyFunction)') in test/emitterSpec.js (line 161)
      test/emitterSpec.js:166:23 <- test/emitterSpec.js:161:27
      loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17

Answer (score 0):

The error says Emitter.on is undefined. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40716523/6767060).

`on` is defined on Emitter instance.

```
class Emitter {
    constructor() {
        console.log('created Emitter!')
    }
    on(event, callback) {
        console.log('on')
    }
}

a = new Emitter()
=> created Emitter!
a.on()
=> on
```

Comment: Thanks i tried doing it but not working. i changed the browser from phantomJs to chrome and i get this type error: Emitter.on is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that error. i had to export the function to the tests and changed the browser to chrome in  karma.conf.js file . Now i get this TypeError: Cannot read property 'event_name_one' of undefined. I have it defined

```
var Emitter = function () {
    this.events = {};
    var Event_Name_One;

} ;
export function on (event, listener) {
    if (typeof this.events[event] !== 'object') {
        this.events[event] = [];
    }

    this.events[event].push(listener);
};
```

and in test.js

```
// Testing event names
    const EVENT_NAME_ONE = 'event_name_one';

describe('#on', () => {
        it('should subscribe to an event name and be called when triggered', () => {
            Emitter.on(EVENT_NAME_ONE, spyFunction);
            Emitter.trigger(EVENT_NAME_ONE);

            expect(spyFunction.calls.count()).toBe(1);
        });
```

I don't understand why i get this error. Can anyone provide help regarding this.thanks.